# Smallest connected subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G=(V, E)$ I want to split V in two subsets $V_1$ and $V_2$ that satisfy the following conditions:

1) The nodes in $V_1$ should not be connected to each other. In formula:
$NumberConnectedComponents(V_1) = Cardinality(V_1) $

2) The nodes in $V_2$ can be connected with nodes in $V_1$ and $V_2$ $i.e.$ there isn't any restriction on the structure of $V_2$.

3) I want $V_2$ to be as small as possible.  $V_2$ should be the smallest subset of $V$ such that both (1) and (2) hold.

Questions:

1 )Is there a commonly used concept associated to this type of factorization? 
The Dominating Set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set seems to be  a similar but not equivalent concept.

2) If yes, is there and algorithm to compute it efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a largest [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) in the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) of $G$.

This is known to be a hard problem -- even finding out *whether* there's a possible $V_1$ of a given size is NP-complete.

Comment: That is also known as ​ "an [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) in $G$." . ​ ​ ​ ​